# SQL Server: Capturing All the columns that have changed in a separate table

Tags: sql-server

In my SQl Server I have a table of around 40 attributes/columns. There is a daily load which might update any of these columns. I want to capture the changes in these columns in a separate table with a reason code column telling which column value changed. There might be instances where more than one column value might get changed in a single daily load, in that case the changed log table should capture all these changes separately in rows with each row depicting the individual change.

For Example:

TableA(column1(pk),column2,column3,column4)
values(1,100,ABC,999)

**After update**:

TableA(column1(pk),column2,column3,column4)

values(1,100,ACD,901)

**The corresponding change log table should have two entries:**

TabChangeLog(column1,before,after,reason);

values(1,ABC,ACD,'column3 changed')

values(1,999,901,'column4 changed')

I tried implementing this through triggers but am not able to figure out a way to separate each of these changes in separate rows when there are more than one changes. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a trigger like :

```
create trigger trigger_name
instead of update as

if update(column1)
begin
insert into TabChangeLog
select inserted.column1, inserted.column3, deleted.column3, 'column3', 'update/change'
from inserted i inner join deleted d 
on i.column1 = d.column2
end

if update(column2)
begin
insert into TabChangeLog
select inserted.column1, inserted.column2, deleted.column2, 'column2', 'update/change'
from inserted i inner join deleted d 
on i.column1 = d.column2
end
...
```

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/instead-of-update-triggers-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 has a thing called Temporal Tables which would probably simplify your job a lot.  It lets you rewind a dataset through time to see the changes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

If you don't want to go that route and use triggers instead.  UPDATE triggers have two tables `inserted` and `deleted` that let you know what the row state was before and after.

*Edit: These are tables so you have to use SELECT INTO etc to interact with them you can't do conditional logic (if /else)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Tail] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
)


CREATE TABLE Table1_Audit
(
Audit varchar(100)
)

--drop trigger Table1_OnUPDATE

CREATE TRIGGER Table1_OnUPDATE 
   ON  dbo.Table1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    INSERT INTO Table1_Audit ([Audit])
    select CONCAT('Tail changed to' ,inserted.Tail,' for pk Id=',inserted.Id) from inserted inner join
    deleted on inserted.Id = deleted.Id  --pk must be the same
    where
    inserted.Tail <> deleted.Tail --field x must be different

END
GO

--truncate table Table1_Audit

--update Table1 set Tail = 5

select * from Table1_Audit
```